# Run Java 8 application on eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-8

We want to update our eclipse RCP application (plugin based) to Java 8. Traditionally it is running with Java7 with target platform **eclipse indigo 3.7**. I have used Luna(e4) to build application with Java 8 compliance level. When I try to run the application with eclipse indigo 3.7 - it gives me following error. My question is - is it possible to run Java8 application on eclipse 3.7?

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle <packagename> could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY <packagename> 4 0 2014-12-30 11:24:03.857
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle  <packagename> could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

etc. (I get this error for every required plugin in the application)
```

Comment: 3.7 obviously does not know about the JavaSE-1.8 execution environment so I think it is very unlikely that you can run code requiring Java 8

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code does not require Java 8 to compile - it compiles well with Java7 and runs on target eclipse 3.7 but when we changed building environment to Java 8 it builds but does not run on eclipse 3.7. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For all your plugins change the required execution environment to JavaSE-1.7.

You can do this in the MANIFEST.MF editor. The Execution Environment is specified on the Overview tab of the editor.  Also click the 'Update the classpath settings' link.